# Apache 2.2 - You don't have permission to access site on this server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, permissions, server, httpd.conf

Hello I am using Server version: Apache/2.2.22 running Ubuntu 12.04.5 . I had my website on another server which was running correctly with 750 permissions to whole folder. When I moved to the new server :

I created the virtual host and I turned it on (a2ensite, reload and restart apache)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/project/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I set permissions of the project folder to 750 and I get the error :

```
(13)Permission denied: /path/to/project/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

I cleared .htaccess file but I got the same error. SELinux is not installed and my httpd.conf file is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: provide **chmod 444 /path/to/project/.htaccess** and restart nginx

Comment: @shahin nginx: unrecognized service